# Rest API Call in uipath

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-activity, uipath-api

My requirement is to fetch the data from rest api data and store it in separate variable. I had the endpoint url(https://abcdev.service-now.com/api/now/table/sc_multi_row_question_answer?sysparm_query=parent_id%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&sysparm_display_value=true&sysparm_exclude_reference_link=true&sysparm_fields=variable_set%2Cvalue%2Citem_option_new%2Crow_index).This is fetching the datas for all 3 rows. But i wants that this user needs to be added in this delegate access like that.[image]

I have attached the image for which field i want to fetch.
I wants to fetch user to be added,level of access required,inbox,calender,tasks,contacts,notes,journal,select required send rights for these field i wants to fetch row by row.kindly assist me in that.

Comment: Your API request is returning the data from service now as a JSON blob.  You likely need to simply deserialize this into a datatable or an array that you can then iterate over, though the question isn't really clear to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

You will receive the response in JSON with all the rows, but you can use de serialize JSON Array activity to de serialize the JSON in each record with all the columns you have mentioned.

And Once you have the rows in the array JSON you can loop through it and get the details for each field.